# Vector Spaces V and W with linear transformation T: V --> W statements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

I'm in a little slump with this question.  I have a general idea, but I don't know exactly which theorem to pair them up with because I think that it may be too simple.  Here is the question:

[image]

For part (a) I was thinking that if T is a linear transformation, and if T is one-to-one, then it has the trivial solution T(x) = 0.  Doesn't that imply linear independence already, or am I missing a step?

For part (b) I was thinking that X spans V if then it is a subspace of V, but I don't know how it works with span W.

Any tips on these problems?

Comment: You're missing that if it's one-to-one then it has the trivial solution *only*.

Answer (score 0):

The usual route is rewrite $\sum_i c_i T(x_i) = 0$.

For both of those.  Show us exactly where you're getting stuck and you might unstick yourself.